# How Do I Reference Different Sub-Templates from Different Templates in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, spacebars

I have 5 templates. Two Templates call One that, in turn, call the other two depending from which template it was called from.

I want to do the following:

```
<template name="Template1">
   <!-- show his things -->
   {{BaseTemplate SubTemplate1}}
</template>

<template name="Template2">
   <!-- show his things -->
   {{BaseTemplate SubTemplate2}}
</template>

<template name="BaseTemplate">
   {{#each xpto}}
     <!-- show base things -->
     {{BaseTemplate {{CallSubTemplateGiven}} }}
   {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="SubTemplate1">
   <!-- show few things -->
</template>

<template name="SubTemplate2">
   <!-- show other things -->
</template>
```

Is there a way to do it? Could not figure out how to do it with RegisterHelper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it by passing the sub template as an argument to the base template, and then using template.dynamic to render the right one.

```
 <template name="Template1">
               {{> BaseTemplate subtemplate=SubTemplate1 }}
</template>

<template name="Template2">
               {{> BaseTemplate subtemplate=SubTemplate2 }}
</template>

<template name="BaseTemplate">
    {{#each xpto}}
               {{> Template.dynamic template=../subtemplate }}
    {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="SubTemplate1">

</template>


<template name="SubTemplate2">

</template>
```

Comment: Should be `{{> Template.dynamic template=../subtemplate }}` Since the context changes inside the `#each`

Comment: This is Magic! Thank you both for the tip. I wrote a simple test app on MeteorPad to show it off.  I hope I am sharing it the right way: [link] (http://app-jgyecvz8.meteorpad.com/)